# Read value of selected item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to get the value of item, which is selected by user. Please suggest.

`Codepen link: https://codepen.io/udyux/pen/KzJQea?editors=1111`

Comment: I'd do it the regular way - note: you'll probably need some javascript if you want to do anything other than display a static page

Comment: Please post a snippet with your code and what you have tried to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I m using similar code as this link has.

Comment: Please include all code to replicate the problem **in the question it self**. Perferably in the form of a [MCVE]. Make it easy for us to help you by not having to go off site to find your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of a checked ("selected") radio button from the DOM using the name of the radio button set and the id of the enclosing form:

```
let radioValue =
   Array.from( document.getElementById( formId)
  .elements
  .namedItem( radioName))
  .find( element=> element.checked)
 .value;
```

Alternatively (or if the radio inputs are not in a form) run a document query to find the checked radio input:

```js
function getRadioValue( radioName) {
"use strict";
    let radioValue;
    let radioInput = document.querySelector(`input[name="${radioName}"]:checked`);
    if( radioInput) {
        radioValue = radioInput.value;
    }
    return radioValue;
}
```

```html
<div onchange='console.log(getRadioValue("radios"))'>
<input type="radio" name="radios" value = "1">
<input type="radio" name="radios" value = "2">
<input type="radio" name="radios" value = "3">
</div>
```

For `HTMLSelectElement`s use the `selectedIndex` property of the object to look up the selected option element from which to obtain the value.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started

I added a div to the top of the body document

```
<h1 id="display">
    Hello World
</h1>
```

Code below updates that display('hello World') with the relevant value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":radio[id='awesomeness-ridiculous']").change(function() {
        $("#display").html(this.id);
  });
  $(":radio[id='awesomeness-reasonable']").change(function() {
        $("#display").html(this.id);
  });
    $(":radio[id='awesomeness-lacking']").change(function() {
        $("#display").html(this.id);
  });
  $(":radio[id='awesomeness-awesomeless']").change(function() {
        $("#display").html(this.id);
  });
});
```

`this.id` is the code that gets the value of the selected item.

Your question is a little vague so this should be enough to get you started. Hope it helps.

Codepen for reference: https://codepen.io/viewtifulmoejoe/pen/mXBByp?editors=1011

Comment: Please only use jQuery if it is mentioned in the question or the question is tagged with jQuery. At the very least you should mention this uses a third party library.

Comment: @JonP I forked the codepen that the poster linked to. 
Why would I need to mentioned any third party libraries that they are using themself in the link they provided and asked specifically about?